# Login loop in Fedora 28

Tags: fedora, gnome-shell

After updating from Fedora 27 to to 28 when I tried to login, I am facing a login loop. After giving correct password, again login screen is coming. I checked journalctl and saw that gnome-shell is crashing. I have attached a log also. I have tried both wayland ang xorg, the result is same.
log-
https://hastebin.com/raw/tuvuxemilu

Comment: May be this can help https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/108067/login-loop/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had a similar problem and logged in a virtual terminal (ctrl + alt + f2) and disabled all gnome shell extensions with the following command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell enabled-extensions "[]"
```

and then i was able to login again. Apparently an extension called system-monitor crashed my login every time

Answer (score 2):

Did you have `updates-testing` enabled? I think you're probably hitting [this bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1573546) caused by a misconfiguration in an update to Cinnamon. This *should* be resolved by a new update in the pipeline. (The problematic one was there for a few hours before we caught this, unfortunately.)

1. Hit `ctrl-alt-f6` to get a text console. (May need the `Fn` key too on some laptops.
2. Log in
3. Run `sudo dnf upgrade`
4. Notice if you have an update to `caribou`, which in this case is the problematic update.
5. If so, that should fix it. Hit `alt-f1` (no `ctrl` necessary from the text-mode console) to get back to the GUI.

If this *doesn't* fix it (like if the update is not yet available on the mirrors you are hittting), go back to the console and try

1. `dnf remove caribou`
2. or `dnf install cinnamon-settings-daemon`

Because the root of the problem is that caribou (an on-screen keyboard) is no longer used by default in GNOME, but is in Cinnamon, so it's on your system when you upgrade from the previous defaults, and then something in the update isn't defined correctly. If this is the problem, you'll see `Settings schema 'org.cinnamon.desktop.a11y.applications' is not installed` in your system log.

If you *don't* have the testing updates repository enabled, the problem is something else. If you *do* have testing updates enabled, thanks for helping Fedora test — but do realize that occasionally problems like this will get through.

(And, shameless plug: if you'd like to help us so that more things like this are caught automatically before even getting that far, we could use help with our [Continuous Integration](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/CI) initiative.)